Clion can't Identify functions form head file in WSL2
I use clion with WSL2 toolchain. When i include ncurses.h(has already been insntalled) and use "initsrc()", The IDE is giving me an error that it cannot resolve the symbol.But the file can be compiled successfully.  enter image description here
I use clion2024.1.3,WSL2 Debian,gcc 12.2.0
How to fix the error?
